# antd module.exports = exports['default']; is not working

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, antd

As antd described I am using `babel-plugin-import` and I have added following babel loader in webpack config.

webpack.config

```
{
  test: /\.js?$/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  query: {
   presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
   "plugins": [
     ["import", { libraryName: "antd", style: "css" }]
    ]
  }
}
```

MyApp.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Modal, Button, Checkbox, Table, Icon, Badge, Alert, notification, Row, Col } from 'antd';
const { Column, ColumnGroup } = Table;

class MyApp extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   }

   render() {
    let template = <Table dataSource={dataSource} columns={columns} />
    return (template);
   }
}
export default MyApp;
```

The error is

```
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) 
or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. 
Check the render method of `Table`.
    at invariant (invariant.js:44)
    at instantiateReactComponent (instantiateReactComponent.js:74)
    at instantiateChild (ReactChildReconciler.js:44)
    at ReactChildReconciler.js:71
    at traverseAllChildrenImpl (traverseAllChildren.js:77)
    at traverseAllChildrenImpl (traverseAllChildren.js:93)
    at traverseAllChildren (traverseAllChildren.js:172)
    at Object.instantiateChildren (ReactChildReconciler.js:70)
    at ReactDOMComponent._reconcilerInstantiateChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:187)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:226)
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0",
  "repository": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --colors",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --progress --inline --historyApiFallback",
    "start": "npm run dev",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
    "antd": "^2.10.2",
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "babel-core": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate": "^0.5.2",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-flow": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.12.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.11.6",
    "cidr-regex": "^1.0.6",
    "create-react-class": "^15.5.3",
    "d3": "^3.5.16",
    "debug": "2.2.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.0.3",
    "express": "4.9.8",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "filesaver.js": "^0.2.0",
    "fixed-data-table": "0.6.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "formsy-react": "0.17.0",
    "html2canvas": "^0.5.0-beta4",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "manifest-revision-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.0",
    "netmask": "^1.0.5",
    "node-waves": "^0.7.5",
    "normalize-css": "^2.3.1",
    "object-assign": "2.0.0",
    "prop-types": "~15.5.10",
    "react": "~15.5.4",
    "react-axios": "0.0.9",
    "react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.0.0",
    "react-dom": "~15.5.4",
    "react-google-maps": "4.7.2",
    "react-iframe": "0.0.4",
    "react-modal": "~0.6.1",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.0.0",
    "react-tooltip": "^3.3.0",
    "reactable": "0.12.0",
    "rickshaw": "^1.6.0",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "webpack": "2.1.0-beta.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.2.2",
    "baggage-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.10",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "eslint": ">=1.6.0 <4.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "~1.5.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.22.0",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine": "^2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.2.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^0.13.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.5",
    "karma-phantomjs2-launcher": "^0.5.0",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.0",
    "node-static": "^0.7.9",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.0.2",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.1.0-beta.7"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=4.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: May be you should have div tags inside your render method around other child html tags

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your actual datasource and column variable declaration, It is tough to tell as from your error code, It seems you are not providing the arguments to Table in correct format.

Here is an example for datasource and column.

```
const dataSource = [{
  key: '1',
  name: 'Mike',
  age: 32,
  address: '10 Downing Street'
}, {
  key: '2',
  name: 'John',
  age: 42,
  address: '10 Downing Street'
}];

const columns = [{
  title: 'Name',
  dataIndex: 'name',
  key: 'name',
}, {
  title: 'Age',
  dataIndex: 'age',
  key: 'age',
}, {
  title: 'Address',
  dataIndex: 'address',
  key: 'address',
}];
```

Also, I don't know your folder structure, but if your files are in a different folder then you might wanna add something like this to your webpack config.

```
include: path.join(__dirname, 'your_folder_name_goes_here')
```